# Recreate iOS app opening transition with CATransition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm making an iOS app and I'd like to know if you can recreate the animation that occurs when you open an iOS app from the Springboard using `CATransition`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `CATransition` on iOS only provides cross-fading and a few variations of sliding animations.

You will need to use either the `UIView` animation methods (see "Animations" in the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1)) or `CAAnimation` (e.g. `CABasicAnimation`, see the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

In both cases, you'll probably want to animate the `transform` property of the view/layer.

Comment: is there any animation type, or examples?

Comment: I've already linked to the relevant documentation, there are plenty of examples in there.